# Spring boot 2.0.5 and HSQL file db display log out user lacks privilege or object not found when entity include @ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb

for any reason console display below log when I try running my Spring boot 2.0.5 app and *entity* has unilateral @ManyToOne relationships. Console logs will be clear if **@ManyToOne are removed**, app loads fine and no error are shown, though.

DB is set up in application.properties to be created in file (althoug same error log I get if DB is on memory). And log shows right SQL to create tables, FK and insert new pre defined rows ( found in classpath:data.sql )

I checked different post and looks like this issue is not easy to be solved due to many options. Any suggestions? Thanks.

*Update* unfortunately table name is not the issue. I updated to USER_ACCOUNT and I got same error : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.USER_ACCOUNT. It's must be related to annotation @ManyToOne because when I remove it everything load fine

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.USER
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getUserTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlterTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlter(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
... 45 common frames omitted
```

**User Entity**

```
 @Entity
 @Table( name = "USER" )
 @Getter @Setter
 @ToString
 @EqualsAndHashCode
public class User 
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "USER_ID" )
private Integer id;

@Column( name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false  )
private String userName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "USER_STATUS_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_STATUS_ID" , nullable = false )
private UserStatus status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(  name = "USER_ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ROLE_ID", nullable = false  )
private UserRole role;

@JsonIgnore
@Column( name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false  )
private String password;

@Embedded
private Audit audit;
 }
```

**USerRole entity**

```
    @Entity
 @Table( name = "USER_ROLE" )
 @Getter @Setter
 @ToString
 @EqualsAndHashCode
 public class UserRole 
 {
@Id
@Column( name = "USER_ROLE_ID" )
private Integer id;

@Column( name = "USER_ROLE" )
@Enumerated( EnumType.STRING ) 
private UserRoleEnum role;
}
```

**HSQLDB.log**

```
  drop table user if exists
  drop table user_role if exists
  drop table user_status if exists
  drop sequence hibernate_sequence if exists
  create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
  create table user (user_id integer not null, created_on date, 
  updated_on date, password varchar(255) not null, user_name 
  varchar(255) not null, user_role_id integer not null, user_status_id 
  integer not null, primary key (user_id))
   create table user_role (user_role_id integer not null, user_role 
  varchar(255), primary key (user_role_id))
  create table user_status (user_status_id integer not null, 
  user_status varchar(255), primary key (user_status_id))
  alter table user add constraint FKh2wc2dtfdo8maylne7mgubowq foreign 
  key (user_role_id) references user_role
  alter table user add constraint FKo6g0t5ih8a5bsioca8qh5ukg3 foreign 
  key (user_status_id) references user_status
  INSERT INTO USER_STATUS VALUES(1,'PENDING_VERIFIED')
  COMMIT
  INSERT INTO USER_STATUS VALUES(2,'ACTIVE')
  COMMIT
  INSERT INTO USER_ROLE VALUES(1,'ADMIN')
  COMMIT
  INSERT INTO USER_ROLE VALUES(2,'USER')
```

COMMIT

Comment: `USER` is a keyword in SQL and should not be used as table name. Try changing it to `USERS`

Comment: unfortunately table name is not the issue. I updated to USER_ACCOUNT and I got same error : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.USER_ACCOUNT.

it's must be related to annotation @ManyToOne because when I remove it everything load fine

Answer (score 0):

You can not user User as a Table name as it is a reserved word. see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

There are two solutions.

1.Change Entity name from User to Users.

2.Use backticks if still you want to use a reserved word.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE interval (begin INT, end INT);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax.
near 'interval (begin INT, end INT)'

mysql> CREATE TABLE `interval` (begin INT, end INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

I would recommend you to go for 1st solution.

Comment: unfortunately table name is not the issue. I updated to USER_ACCOUNT and I got same error : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.USER_ACCOUNT.

it's must be related to annotation @ManyToOne because when I remove it everything load fine